# .close() does not seem to work python CSV

Tags: python, csv

I specifically call f.close() on the CSV yet when i run the code it returns the error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Student Data.csv'
```

I have absolutely no idea why the file is not closed, any help would be greatly appreciated, many Thanks

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv
import os

def deleteuser():
    def deleteanaccount(searchusername):
        f = open('Student Data.csv', 'r')
        r = csv.reader(f)
        lines = [l for l in r]
        f.close()
        usernamelist = []
        for item in lines:
            usernamelist.append(item[0])        
        x = usernamelist
        for i in range(0, len(usernamelist)):
            if searchusername == usernamelist[i]:
                print(i)
                del(lines[i])
            os.remove('Student Data.csv')
            writer = csv.writer(open('Student Data.csv', 'w', newline=''))
            writer.writerows(lines)


    def clickdelete():
        y = whichaccount.get()
        deleteanaccount(y)


    deleteuserwindow = Tk()
    deleteuserwindow.iconbitmap("hXYTZdJy.ico")
    deleteuserwindow.title("Remove a User")
    whichaccount = Entry(deleteuserwindow)
    whichaccount.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 20)
    Button(deleteuserwindow, text = "Submit", command = clickdelete, height = 4, width = 10).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    deleteuserwindow.mainloop()

deleteuser()
```

Comment: You're calling `os.remove('Student Data.csv')` inside a `for` loop. It will only work the first time...

Comment: Can you tell us which line you get the error on? I don't know why people keep this type of thing a secret here on SO.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake sorry it was the fact i was calling it in the loop @martineau

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of the rest of your code, I'm guessing what you want to do is re-write your CSV file only once after you're done pruning your data (`lines` I suppose):

```
    for i in range(0, len(usernamelist)):
        if searchusername == usernamelist[i]:
            print(i)
            del(lines[i])

    # Don't do this stuff until the loop is done
    os.remove('Student Data.csv')
    writer = csv.writer(open('Student Data.csv', 'w', newline=''))
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Apolgies in advance if I've misinterpreted your code's intent.

Comment: use enumerate not range